# How to call web services into jsp page

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a web services written in java using jersey framework when i call it it will return me a xml. But i want to use it in a jsp page for example i have a web service getCoutry() when i call it, it will return me xml as like.

my url is: http://localhost:8080/countries-ws/resources/admin/getCountry?id=1

```
<conList>
<cid>1</cid>
<iso>AD</iso>
<iso3>AND</iso3>
<name>ANDORRA</name>
<numcode>20</numcode>
<printableName>Andorra</printableName>
</conList>
```

And i want to use it in a select tag of jsp page.
I don't know how to use it please help me guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the webservice from your servlet . set the result in request/session or appropriate scope as attribute and forward this to jsp.  on jsp access it using JSTL as simple as that

**Update:**

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            yahoo.openStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);

in.close();
```

- [Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

Comment: Thanks Jigar, But i don't know how to do it please give me a example i really great need of it

Comment: which part you aren't clear about, jsp/servlet stuff or consuming webservices ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, I have a url of web service that is runing on my tomcat server. and i am confused about how to call it from where i start it and how to call it through servlet.

Comment: if you make GET to your URL and it returns this XML ,[you can use HTTPURLConnection to make GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: if possible than plz give me a simple example